# Finding constants of a general solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I have derived the following solution to a given differential equation, regarding simple harmonic motion:
$$x(t)=c_1 \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right)+c_2\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right).$$
I am trying to find the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

I have found $c_1$, by considering:
$$x(0)=c_1 \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}(0)\right)+c_2\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}(0)\right).$$
which leads to $$x_0=c_1.$$
However, I am unsure as how to find the second one:
I have attempted to find it but I am convinced that I am wrong:
Considering: $$x'(0)=v(0)=-c_1\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\sin \left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}(0)\right)+c_2\cos \left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}(0)\right)\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$
This would return a constant, $c_2$ of:
$$v_0\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}.$$
As I said, I am convinced this is wrong, if anyone could offer me some advice as to how to find the actual value, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this, but then the constant becomes a function of n, hence is not a constant

Answer (score 1):

Why you are convinced that your computations are wrong ? Everything is fine:

$c_1=x_0$ and $c_2= v_0\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}.$